# c++ if (DEBUG) ... expected primary-expression before '==' token

Tags: c++, expression

```
  #define DEBUG 1

  void senddata() {
  ...
  if (DEBUG==1) {
  cout << row->Printable () << endl;
  };

  ....
  }
```

getrow.cc: In function 'void senddata()':
getrow.cc:277: error: expected primary-expression before '==' token

IMO that code was running some days ago... - Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: At a guess, something is undefining DEBUG.

Comment: yep I renamed it and it's fine. I changed the build environment recently and the new system seems to define/undefine DEBUG . You Want to copy it in an answer , unapersson?

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't do it like that at all. This seems more appropriate:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    cout << row->Printable() << endl;
#endif
```

This also generates better warnings and errors if you are doing something wrong (like forgot a semicolon somewhere).